# Quantum Mechanism Dipole Moment Magnetic Field Problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, angular-momentum, physical-chemistry

[image]

[image]

I figured 1a out pretty easily.

For **1b** I am a bit stuck. 
So far i have that in the field: $$
\Delta z = v_0t + (1/2) a_zt
$$
$$
F_z = ma_z
$$
so
$$
a_z = F_z/m
$$
We know
$$
F_z=\mu_z(\partial(B_z)/\partial(z))
$$
So knowing the time we can find the displacement $$\Delta(z)$$

Out of the field its constant veloctiy so
$$\Delta(z)=v_{out}*t$$

What can i do to relate these though to find the minimum gradient.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: I dont see how this question is a "check my work" problem. It also does not really disagree with the PSE terms.

Answer (score 0):

The atom is only being accelerated vertically with $F_z/m$ in $z$ direction as it passes through the $1m$ long magnet. Since you know the horizontal velocity, you also know the time $t_1$ for the acceleration.

After passing the magnet the atom moves with a constant velocity both in horizontal and in vertical directions, where the vertical velocity is
$$v_z=\frac{F_z}{m} t_1.$$ By writing down four equations of motion in this style and solving them you can obtain the value of $F_z$.